# Как вызвать метод java

Tags: java

Проблема в следующем, при выполнении кода метод (метод 1) вызывает другой метод (метод 2), но что-бы не увеличивать код нужно вызвать из "метода 2" "метод 1" с новыми параметрами не теряя параметры первого вызова "метода 1".

Надеюсь суть понятно, хоть и запутанно вышло.
Есть способ это сделать??

Comment: сделай их глобальными, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например добавить аргументы к первому методу (если там очень много, будет целесообразнее передать массив, или список, как удобнее), которые впоследствии будут переданы второму методу.

```
public void method1(..., Object... args) {
    ...
    method2(..., args);
}

public void method2(..., Object... args) {
    ...
    /* Тут можно аргументы от первого метода (args) добавить 
     * в список, и к нему новые добавить, и этот же массив передать дальше
     * 
     * Вот пример кода:
     * ArrayList<Object> argsAccumulate = Arrays.asList(args);
     * argsAccumulate.add(new Object());
     *
     * method(..., argsAccumulate.toList(new Object[0]));
     */
    method1(..., args); 
}
```

Вот как-то так, надеюсь, я правильно понял суть вопроса.

Comment: С такими методами стоит не забывать что это бесконечный цикл, который приведёт к переполнению стека

Comment: Я думаю, что автор вполне в состоянии понять, что рекурсия должна иметь какое-то условие прерывания :)